# Going over the dataframe to locate rows where there is datetime.datetime object

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

Suppose I have the following dataframe:

```
d = {'col1':['a','b','c'],
    'col2':['d','e', date(2019, 4, 13)],
    'col3':[1,date(2015, 5, 10),3]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

I want to locate the rows where there is `datetime` objects. The outcome would be

```
 index col1        col2        col3
0      1    b           e  2015-05-10
1      2    c  2019-04-13           3
```

The reason I am asking this is because in my actual dataframe I get the following error:

```
TypeError: must be real number, not datetime.datetime
```

Meaning, somewhere in the dataframe there is a `datetime.datetime` value where it should not be. So I want to go through the who dataframe and find exactly those rows by object type and drop them eventually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `applymap`:

```
mask = df.applymap(lambda x: type(x) == datetime.date).any(1)
df[mask]
```

Output:

```
  col1        col2        col3
1    b           e  2015-05-10
2    c  2019-04-13           3
```